# count the all employees and also whose has above 5000 of salary in mongodb between timerange

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

count the all employees and also whose has above 5000 of salary in mongodb between timerange

```
UserStayedTime.collection.aggregate({"$match" => {"starttime"=> { "$gte" => start_date.to_time.utc.beginning_of_day},"endtime" => {"$lte" => end_date.to_time.utc.end_of_day}}}, "count1" => {'$salary' => {"$gte" => 5000 } } , "count"=>{ "$sum"=> 1} )
```

Then i am getting error, can anyone help me, Thanks

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: The statement is not valid. You seem to be combining operations that need to be in a [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage in your `$match`. Group separately to your match.

Answer (score 0):

`UserStayedTime.where("starttime" => { "$gte" => start_date.to_time.utc.beginning_of_day}, "endtime" => {"$lte" => end_date.to_time.utc.end_of_day}, "salary" => {"$gte" => 5000 }).count`